# Azure Active Directory B2C のポリシー内にあるTechnicalProfileのValidationTechnicalProfilesについて

Tags: azure

ValidationTechnicalProfilesについてですが、TechnicalProfileのProtocolが
セルフアサート以外で使用できないかどうか知りたく思います。

本来やりたいことはREST APIが参照できずに500のinternal server errorとなった場合は、
エラーが発生せずに次のステップへ処理が進むようにしたいです。
それでエラーを回避する方法はValidationTechnicalProfilesぐらいしか検討がつかず、
かといってClaimsTransformationProtocolProviderでは
ValidationTechnicalProfilesが反応しないので、セルフアサート以外ではできないのか知りたいです。

またValidationTechnicalProfiles以外で、ポリシー内で500のinternal server errorを
回避する方法があればご教授いただけたらと思います。

**〇UserJourneyから呼んでいるOrchestrationStepの一部**

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <!-- check existing session -->
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>AlternativeSecurityId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>AlternativeSecurityId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
    <!-- ダミー用 -->
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmailDummy" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

**〇OrchestrationStep Order="2"のClaimsExchangeでダミーとして作成しているTechnicalProfile**

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmailDummy">
  <DisplayName>dummy</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <InputClaims/>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="dummyVal2" DefaultValue="false" />
  </InputClaims> -->
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- consent result -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="dummyVal1" DefaultValue="dummy" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="dummyVal2" DefaultValue="false" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="status" PartnerClaimType="status"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="status" PartnerClaimType="userMessage"/>
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="IsDummy" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="VAL-TECHNICAL" ContinueOnError="true"/>
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="XXXX" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**〇ダミーとして作成しているTechnicalProfileのValidationTechnicalProfilesから呼んでいるRESTのTechnicalProfile**

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="VAL-TECHNICAL">
  <DisplayName>VAL-TECHNICAL</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://XXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims> 
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="status" PartnerClaimType="status" DefaultValue="500" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userMessage" PartnerClaimType="userMessage" DefaultValue="NG" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="XXXXXXX" />
```